# how to add multiple background images on a page but NOT stacked on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I want the background images to be horizontally on top of each other. So for instance:

PIC 1

PIC 2

PIC 3

Right now, the only solutions I'm seeing to this problem are to stack the photos because that's what most people are asking about, but I don't want to stack the photos. I just want them to be touching each other (or not, that's fine too) but not on top of each other (from a 3d point of view). The reason why I'm still using them as background images, in case you're wondering, is because I want there to be text on the images, as well as anything else I want to implement. Also, I like having the background-size as cover, but I need to change the formatting so that the position of the two images do not overlap.

Comment: Just put each pic as an img inside a container together with some absolutely positioned text.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dakata911/pen/pdqmOj?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Background image placement, sizing and cropping is a rather complex matter in CSS, for a very simple reason: to cover all possible cases.

Now, in theory, you could use a ***comma separated list of URL's***, inside the **`background-image`** property and also specify the following properties (if needed) as lists of comma separated properties:

- `background-attachment`
- `background-clip`
- `background-image`
- `background-origin`
- `background-position`
- `background-repeat`
- `background-size`

Needless to say, the first item in the list for each of the above applies to the first image, and so on...

For example:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600"), url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x800"), url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/700x700");
  background-position: top center, center center, bottom center;
  background-size: auto 33.33%, auto 33.33%, auto 33.33%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-x;
  
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

If you find it more convenient, you can also use the list notation with the `background` shorthand property, as in:

```css
body {    background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600) repeat-x top center /100% 33.33%, url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x800) repeat-y center center /100% 33.33%, url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x200) repeat-x bottom center /100% 33.33%;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

However, **the real problem** is you are requesting a more advanced logic, which requires background images to influence each other's position, sizing and cropping, pretty much like DOM element would.

Tough luck. That's not possible. Each element in the list of `background-image`s is a separate layer which is rendered by itself, without regard to whether other `background-image` layers exist. The first one is rendered above the second one which is rendered above the third, etc...

If you think about it, considering the array of possible combinations, it's **unrealistic** to request the `background` property of a single element to handle all cases, considering responsiveness.

That's why the proper way to go here, instead of using the `background` property, is to create a child item in your element with the purpose of controlling the background display according to the design specs.

You want to give `.parent` (feel free to change the class name) `position:relative` and give `<background-sizer>` element `position:absolute; width:100%; height: 100%; top:0; left:0;`, making sure it covers the entire area of its closest *positioned* parent. Inside `<background-sizer>` you will probably want to add some dummy `<span>`s to help you control the background, eventually using `@media` queries, if you need them displayed differently on different devices.

Here's an example:

```css
body { 
  margin: 0;
} 
.parent {
  position: relative; 
  padding: 2rem;
}
background-sizer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
background-sizer > span {
  flex: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  border: solid rgba(255,255,255,.35);
  border-width: 1px 0;
}
background-sizer::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
background-sizer > span:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x500);
}
background-sizer > span:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x800);
}
background-sizer > span:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x500);
}
.contents {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.42);
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
}
.some-more-content {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}
body > * {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.contents {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}
.contents:hover {
  opacity: .21;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <background-sizer>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </background-sizer>
  <div class="contents">
    <h2>This is your element</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ultrices in iaculis nunc sed. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit. Platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing. Id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus. At consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac. Faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. At quis risus sed vulputate odio. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. Tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Quisque id diam vel quam elementum. Parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis.
    
    <p>Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing. Lectus quam id leo in vitae. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor. Vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo. Fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim.
    
    <p>Lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia. Sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae. Eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Posuere morbi leo urna molestie at. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Integer vitae justo eget magna. A pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor. Egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod. Libero enim sed faucibus turpis.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="some-more-content">
<h2>And here's some more content</h2>
<p>Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis. In massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis. Sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae. Ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum. Et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor. Sed cras ornare arcu dui.

<p>Id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non. Amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla. Adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Purus semper eget duis at tellus. Integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris. Pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque. Ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed augue. Pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla. Nibh tortor id aliquet lectus. Blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi.
</div>
```

A few notes:

- intended as *proof of concept* (copy/paste won't help you much); you should take the time to read what the properties do, in order to use it. If you don't, chances are you won't be able to adapt it to your needs.
- most likely, you don't need any of the cosmetics (`padding`, `margin`, `color`, etc...)
- i placed a darkening layer on the `<background-sizer>` to make sure the text remains readable, given the images are randomly generated. You probably want to that.

Comment: thanks. so there's no way just to change the background positioning of both images?